# Character ArrayList outOfBounds exception

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, char

Error : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 70, size is 10;

I have created a function to create random Integer ArrayList, and to do some operations with it, now i a m trying to adapt it to Chars,and i got strange error, as it seems to me,the default chars array size is bigger then Integer one, but i am not sure.What can i do with this code?
Function fails here : `numbers.set(rightNumbers.get(k),answer.charAt(k));`

```
 @Override
    public void charactersRandomise(String answer) {
        final String alphabet = "ABSDEFGHMN";
        final int N = alphabet.length();
        ArrayList<Character> numbers = new ArrayList<Character>();
        ArrayList<Character> rightNumbers = new ArrayList<Character>();
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int i=0;
        Log.d("size",String.valueOf(N));
        while (numbers.size() < 10) {

            char random = alphabet.charAt(randomGenerator.nextInt(N));
            if (!numbers.contains(random)) {
                numbers.add(random);
                Log.d("numbers", numbers.get(i).toString());
                i++;
            }
        }
        int j=0;
        while (rightNumbers.size() < answer.length()) {
            char random = alphabet.charAt(randomGenerator.nextInt(N));
            if (!rightNumbers.contains(random)) {
                rightNumbers.add(random);
                Log.d("RightNumbers",rightNumbers.get(j).toString());
                j++;
            }
        }
        for(int k =0;k<rightNumbers.size();k++){
            numbers.set(rightNumbers.get(k),answer.charAt(k));
            Log.d(rightNumbers.get(k)+"", numbers.get(rightNumbers.get(k)).toString());
        }
        for (int h=0;h<numbers.size()-1;h++) {
            Log.d("newNumber", String.valueOf(numbers.get(h)));
        }
        for(int m=0;m<buttons.length;m++){
            buttons[m].setText(numbers.get(m) + "");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Invalid index 70, size is 10;

This actually says it all. You are trying to access the 71st character while there are only 10. Which line throws the Exception?

Comment: When i set new value, it is shown is the question.This fuction works great with Integer, all i have changed is char random = alphabet.charAt(randomGenerator.nextInt(N));
Instead of int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numbers.set(rightNumbers.get(k),answer.charAt(k));` - this expression `rightNumbers.get(k)` retrieves a character. In ASCII this character ( as i can see it is `F`) is converted to the number 70 in `int` and that is why the exception occurs.

Replace this with this:

```
numbers.set(k ,answer.charAt(k));
```

Comment: Thanks!That works great!I have changed rightNumbers array type to Character for some reason =).